# htaccess Redirect : main domain conflict with addon domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains, foo.com (main domain) and bar.com (addon domain) hosted on the same VPS.

Folders:

```
public-html/    (default folder for foo.com)
├── foo/        (desired folder for foo.com)
├── bar/        (default folder for bar.com)
```

I want to force https and www for both domains and to do an *invisible redirect of foo.com to subfolder public_html/foo*

I'm here

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bar.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.foo.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!foo/).*)$ /foo/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.bar.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

  First domain foo.com works as expected but bar.com doesn't work :
- bar.com points to https://www.foo.com. I don't know why
- www.bar.com or http://www.bar.com or https://www.bar.com returns an **Internal 500 Error**

If I delete the following rule, bar.com works and foo.com doesn't work anymore :

```
RewriteRule ^((?!foo/).*)$ /foo/$1 [L]
```

How can I exclude bar.com from being conflicted by this rule ?

Answer (score 0):

This works good :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.bar.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.foo.fr%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com$
RewriteRule !^foo/ /foo%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```